# Is this layout possible to make, FadingActionBar w/ ViewPager?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I've got an layout which i really would like to use but I'm not sure it´s even possible!

I have tried FadingActionbar  from github which works when I have a scrollview for content, but when I change to an ViewPager none of my fragments in it seems to load, and I¨m not able to swipe either to the sides or swipe up the top image.

My viewpager will consist of 3 views. One is an scrollview, and 2 of them are listviews.

I hope you understand what I want to achieve :) When swiping up I want the imageview to slide in under the actionbar and then stop when the PagerSlidingTabs are just under the acitonbar.

[Mockup of what the layout looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNqkv.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is the related github issue

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar/issues/23